# How to safely team up in hostile society?

Tags: society, secret-society

Imagine a situation happening in Nazi Germany around 1940. Person A is a member of secret anti-Nazi group. Person B secretly hates Nazis and is therefore a good candidate for membership.

Now consider three scenarios:

1. Both think the other has anti-Nazi tendencies and want to ACTIVELY get in touch.
2. A thinks B is anti-Nazi and wants to invite him to the group. B has no clue.
3. B thinks A is anti-Nazi and wants to cooperate. A has no clue.

Admitting anti-Nazi tendencies is punishable by death, so in all scenarios both A and B would risk greatly with direct approach. But even if that happens, the other party cannot be sure that it is not some kind of trap. What is the safest way to do get in touch?

I can imagine scenario 1 can be solved by using another person C, completely trusted by both A and B:

> A->C: Hey, is B anti-Nazi? I would like him to join our rebel group.

> B->C: Hey, is A anti-Nazi? I would like to start or join some kind of rebel group.

> C->A: Yes, B is anti-Nazi and wants to join you.

> C->B: Yes, A is anti-Nazi and wants you in his rebel group.

Is there safer solution for scenario 1? What are the safest solutions for scenarios 2 and 3, if any? Thank you very much.

Comment: Welcome to worldbuilding. If you check our [help], you see we help you with the rules of your fictional world, not with plot elements like the one you are asking here.

Comment: For reference and your researches: [The Prisoner's dilemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prisoner's_dilemma).

Comment: This is [game theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Game_theory) rather than worldbuilding. I'm not sure where else might be able to provide useful answers on the subject, but there's certainly lots of information out there.

Comment: A has known B for a long time, and they have been friends, then close friends, for sufficient time. Both A and B know for sure that neither works for the secret police. (Because they actually work, are good at what they do, are slightly non-conformist, have the wrong background, read foreign books etc.) A sounds off B for some technically illegal but nevertheless low-risk activity, like throwing paper airplanes in the auditorium during a stuffy Party speech. If B goes along, they now share a tiny little anti-communist partnership. Maybe B or maybe A has other similar close friends...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**One approaches the other about an unrelated common endeavor.**

Maybe a business proposition.    For a story it would be exciting if it were a crime.  Asking a person to be a partner in any common endeavor is an expression of trust that the other person will hold up their end.  A crime requires even more trust.  It might be a crime like stealing a truckload of pants that would not be punishable by death if caught, but the two of them are in it together.

Once they have common purpose and have established trustworthiness one of them might drop a hint; make a face after Nazis go by or what have you.  Once they have established rapport it will be easier to go on to other matters, like being anti Nazi together.  Or being lovers.  Or both!